# Application circuit G3NA-210B

Tags: relay, datasheet, emc, bom

Simple doubt about EMC directive on page 15.

Should I use the varistor, cap and toroidal core on non UTU model? I want it to be compliant with safety directives, but I dont want to interfere with function and know if I can cut the BOM on those components.

Main use will be HPS lamps and similar loads.

**Product** https://www.mouser.es/ProductDetail/Omron-Automation-and-Safety/G3NA-210B-UTU-DC5-24?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsLmE2CU4Kkzy5Et0ECO1IY

**Circuit mentioned**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXe6m.jpg

Comment: Directive [2014/30/EU](https://www.bsigroup.com/en-GB/our-services/product-certification/ce-mark/eu-directives/electromagnetic-compatibility-directive-emc-2014-108-ec/)?

Comment: @Andy aka yes, I guess it is. But I have non UTU units on BOM and dont know if I can use the application circuit for them

Comment: There is no application circuit.